# How much suffering is needed for an overall happy life?

Tags: meaning-of-life, happiness, introduction-to-philosophy

Premise: I have not studied Philosophy, and maybe I am out of context.

My question arises from two simple considerations:

- Empirically, there seems to be no true happiness without some suffering (extreme example: happiness given by chemical drugs is not long-lasting and always has a destructive effect; happiness and fulfillment often come from overcoming something - although this is indeed questionable)
- Happiness and suffering are not balanced: it is easy to think of people who have had an unhappy life (severe physical conditions, discrimination, life events...)

There must be some sweet spot in-between (I guess no one ever argued that one could be "simply happy"). Could someone provide direction for deepening this thought?

Comment: good question! iirc a similar question about extreme mental and physical suffering, which violates the integrity of the sufferer, makes no sense and is always illegitimate, came up, i think in discussion of williams.

Comment: here is the [chapter](https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/9781400827107.331/html?lang=en) aside from "unbearable suffering", i will offer no answer

Comment: "*It is those who abandon the quest for happiness who are, for Nietzsche, the greatest humans, for their appreciation of intellectual and personal development through their suffering... Thought and artistic creativity is theorised by Gilles Deleuze to have a direct correlation to violence or violent confrontation, in order that those thoughts otherwise suppressed by conventionality may emerge.*" [Siobhan Lyons, On Happiness](https://philosophynow.org/issues/100/On_Happiness)

Comment: "I'm most happy" beamed the fakir. "What?!! You're sittin' on a friggin' cactus!!" Johnson exclaimed.

Comment: please note that @Conifold is obviously offering [one account](https://dspace.wlu.edu/bitstream/handle/11021/22882/WLURG38_Mathews_PHIL_2011.pdf?sequence=8&isAllowed=y) among competitors, which may or may not conflict with what you meant

Comment: "there seems to be no true happiness without some sort of suffering".  There is no *up* without *down*, nor *left* without *right*, and *male* without *female*.  Likewise, there cannot be *happiness* without *unhappiness*.

Comment: How much suffering is needed for an overall happy life?
i think it just only need 5 minute

Comment: 'Empirically there seems' ?  Is there proof or not? If not then there is not empirical evidence, There is anecdotal evidence for which you give an example.  Don't mistake correlation for an interdependance. Even if some form of suffering is inevitable it doesn't mean that it's necessary in order to experience an on balance surfeit of happiness.

Comment: @charmer So, do you believe there has been a human being who lived their full life (let's say, up to and beyond full adult development) who was always, consistently, overall, happy? Also, according to you, physical evidence does not exist, because in principle it could come from repeated fortunate observations (there are no mathematical proofs for physical laws: just phenomenal observations)

Comment: "chemical drugs"... what's a non-chemical drug?

Comment: @RonJohn Gambling

Comment: Gambling is a *metaphorical* drug.  Sure, the "gambling rush" releases dopamine, but dopamine is a chemical.

Comment: @RonJohn Your first remark was already quite useless. Now you realized your blunder and you're making it silly. Please go ahead if you wish. Not gonna interfere.

Comment: The impreciseness of your question has already been noted.  This is just more notice of your impreciseness.

Comment: @rod, I don't know there may well have been, or there may yet be the possibility that someone will live their life consistently, overall happy?  I'm not offering proof, I don't have to offer proof to claim that something is a possibility. However proof may be needed to show a positive correlation between suffering and happiness.  ON that subject 'empirical' doesn't mean mathematical proof.  but scientific evidence that can be quantified.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I recommend this Alan Watts talk, '[Happiness Is Not The Meaning Of Life](https://youtu.be/RsdoJ9x8IBs)'.

I suggest what you are asking is, exactly how much food should I eat to be happy?

Starving will make you unhappy, eating only sweets will make you fat and get diabetes. Eating good food can make you happy, and feel good. But sensory pleasure and pain are just a guide, to sustaining your body. And while they require some attention, the risks are they become a distraction, not a guide or platform.

The real issue that matters, is not happiness anymore than pleasure, it is: How do you live a meaningful life? That question will return to you as you look back on and judge your life, not whether you suffered 'enough'. But, did your suffering *matter*?

I like Rebecca Newberger Goldstein on '[Mattering Matters](https://secularhumanism.org/2017/01/cont-mattering-matters/)', for humanist thinking on living a life with significance to ourselves.

> "I don't know why we are here, but I'm pretty sure that it is not in
> order to enjoy ourselves." -Wittgenstein

Comment: i am not sure if happiness is a broader term than you give it credit for. it certainly is if it is considered the telos of human life. likewise, it depends on what is "meaning"

Comment: i think, and google skills seem to confirm, that wittgenstein wanted us to have a "happy" life, and felt that would make it meaningful. that doesn't mean transient states of euphoria and bliss are meaningful and suffice, but then there are no easy answers for what does

Comment: it's hard to verbalise what that "happiness" truly is. like pleasure and hedon in general, i think you do know (unlike "meaning")

Comment: @zero: You might like this answer: 'Would people do moral things if it didn’t make them physically feel good? If not, how is morality different from any other want?' https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/95579/would-people-do-moral-things-if-it-didn-t-make-them-physically-feel-good-if-not/95621#95621 I would argue we reset our goals, the things we declare recieving will make us happy, in a larger process of reflection that I think is best captured by, searching for meaning. Happiness is a flag we plant on what we want, it is not how we decide what to want.

Comment: that makes sense as an explanation of moral striving, but i don't think it is necessary. perhaps we are just moral because it is coherent to be, in some sense, in our practical reasoning, rather than our "life"

Comment: @zero: Consider the issue of wisdom, as discussed here 'Wisdom and John Vervaeke's awakening from the meaning crises?' https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/82325/wisdom-and-john-vervaekes-awakening-from-the-meaning-crises/82333#82333 I would relate this skill of wisdom, at integrating our needs, & solving dilemmas from a position of having done that, to skill at finding meaning in life. To aim for happiness or pleasure alone is to live 'the unexamined life'. Consider how Socrates actively chose hemlock over exile, because living his principles was more meaningful, & hence his legacy

Comment: you're not going to convince me there is only way to know we should be moral, not without citing someone who agrees with you on how, and maybe even then, given i don't think i was ever moral in order for my life to "mean" more

Comment: @zero: Where did i even imply that..? My point is happiness & suffering are just tags we use to organise experience. We can't simply follow the tags: bit of 1, bit of other. Because how we allocate those tags is a choice - 1 that comes down to a *framework*, based on what is meaningful - a thing we can get more skillful at identifying by beoming wise. You are asking for a hedonuc cheat-sheet, I am saying you'll have to *think*. Comments aren't for extended discussion. Open a chat room if you like. Otherwise I shall cease here.

Comment: i certainly did not ask anything about hedon (which is not to say i find hedon useless in the pursuit of truth and the good). i don't know where you get that mistaken impression (mine was from your claim that morality is not just what we want because the former involves "a larger process of reflection that I think is best captured by, searching for meaning). i would pleasingly trade you many - perhaps not all - meaningful lives for a meaningfully happy one. which is not to say i have suffered too much, nor not enough

Comment: There's a reason, I suppose, why the question remains unanswered. What piques me interest is if there are reason*s* why this is the case. There's a thread, unfortunately on another forum as per my memory (I drank too much of *Lethe* water), that gets to the crux of the issue. If you wish to find it, asking me is as good as guessing where it could be. By the by, we don't even know what life is.

Answer (score 9):

This chat on virtue ethics may be of interest to you:  https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144709/virtue-ethics  The "unhappiness needed" is which we need in order to develop virtues.  It is far less than what is in the world, and the quantity is not set by ontology or moral principles, but by the nature of human psychology.  And as our psychology is different between people, the "minimum" answer will be individual too.

Answer (score 5):

> There seems to be no true happiness without some sort of suffering

Suffering is patently a part of life, from the discomfort of being born into the world to the that of succumbing to death and disease at the end of it with plenty of it in between. In the Buddhist tradition, one of the principles aims is to reduce suffering by recognizing that life is suffering as one of the [Four Noble Truths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_Noble_Truths). In the philosophical tradition of the West, the pursuit of eudaimonia, [hedone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hedone), and ataraxia were central focal points of a number of groups such as the Hedonists and the Stoics. So your observation is endorsed globally and might be seen as part of the [human condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_condition).

> Happiness given by chemical drugs is not long-lasting and always has a destructive effect; happiness and fulfillment often come from overcoming something - although this is indeed questionable

Be careful not to conflate happiness with pleasure. Pleasure often leads to unhappiness, and happiness often requires some amount of suffering.

> There must be some sweet spot in-between (I guess no one ever argued that one can be "simply happy"). Could someone provide direction for deepening this thought?

Sweet spot? For some psychoanalysts, the sweet spot is called becoming your [true self](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/True_self_and_false_self). Sartre riffed heavily on [existentialist notions of self-authenticity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Existentialism). Many philosophers of the 19th and 20th centuries have given a lot of thought to happiness and the purpose of life. Nietzsche had his [will to power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Will_to_power), Maslow called it [self-actualization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-actualization), and Viktor Frankl counseled us in his [*Man's Search for Meaning*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man%27s_Search_for_Meaning) to find meaning as a survivor of the Holocaust.

Ultimately, a thinker often goes through [existential anxiety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anxiety#Existential), and has to come to terms with their mortality, proclivity to suffer, and the [uncertainty of knowledge (IEP)](https://iep.utm.edu/fallibil/) and life in general. The ultimate step in existentialist thinking is to find happiness in the face of suffering by abandoning any hope of a meaningful life, and finding meaning in small things rather than a lifelong narrative foisted upon us by the supernatural or even by ourselves. Such views are considered by [absurdism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absurdism).

Answer (score 2):

Some people say that happiness and sadness are two sides of the same coin. It is true, but I like to think of it this way :

> Sadness is the glass and happiness is the water. The bigger the glass,
> the more water you can hold.

The vice versa is true, where happiness is the glass and sadness is the water.

**the more sadness you have experienced, the more happiness you can feel.**

### An example is given below for both situations :

1. Sadness is the glass and happiness is the water.

> A rich person eats his food. It is tasty for him and he likes
> it. He is satisfied, **but not happy** per se. A poor person
> starving for most of their life eats the same food. It is the best
> thing he ever had in his life and will be for a long time. It is the **happiest moment of his life**. The person eating his food was
> satisfied with his meal. This was because he didn't have the
> experience of starving. On the other hand, the poor person loves the
> food and is very much happy, as he knows that good food is hard to
> come by.
> 2. Happiness is the glass and sadness is the water.

> A poor person starves for a week. It is nothing new to him. He has
> never felt the feeling of having a full meal and he has accepted his
> life as such. **He is sad. But he carries on with whatever he is
> doing.** A rich person's business failed and he goes bankrupt. He has
> nothing left on him. He became poor. Now, he starves for a week.
> Guess what happens. **He feels like he is being tortured. He feels
> like he is going to die. He is on the verge of tears.** This is because he remembers when he was not hungry and was content with his food. **He remembers how delicious it was.**

So long story short, the more suffering you have experienced, the happier you can get and vice versa.

=======================================================================================

Answer (score 2):

### More "simple consideration" needed

> Empirically, there seems to be no true happiness without some sort of suffering

Define "true happiness" and "suffering".  Until you can express what you mean by those terms, you aren't ready to ask the question - and you certainly shouldn't ask other people to *answer* the question.

Your examples don't cut it as explanation because they're factually and logically wrong.

> happiness given by chemical drugs is not long lasting and always has a destructive effect

Not necessarily.  Sure, drugs only last for as long as they're in your system, but there's nothing impossible about keeping them topped up.  There's no absolute reason for all drugs to have some negative side-effects, only body physiology, and body physiology is not a moral framework.

> happiness and fulfilment often come from overcoming something

And why does that count as "suffering"?  I feel happy and fulfilled when I've built something around my house.  I've overcome that challenge.  But I don't have to dislike the building process in order to feel happy and fulfilled.

For a really obvious example of happiness being unrelated to any of that, consider love.  Simply being with the other person is all that's necessary for happiness.  Doesn't need drugs, isn't related to obstacles before they met or obstacles during the relationship, can be long lasting, isn't destructive.  (Love isn't destructive, only other feelings such as jealousy which are ascribed to "love" but really aren't.) Hell, it doesn't even have to be a person - you can love your pets, and you can even love your concept of a god.

#### More thought needed about who says it's a "happy life"

> it is easy to think of people who have had an overall unhappy life (severe physical conditions, discriminations, life events...)

By your terms, looking from the outside, you might think so.  Do those factors make them think *they* have an overall unhappy life, though?  Some do, some don't.  And conversely, some people may have extreme privilege (sports stars, movie stars, pop stars) and still consider themselves to have an unhappy life, even though they don't have any of the issues that your so-called "unhappy" people do.

Do you think you have any right, responsibility or ability to pass judgement on whether someone's life is "overall happy"?

#### More research needed

> I guess no one ever argued that one can be "simply happy"

Of course they have.  The entire religion/philosophy of Buddhism is centred around it.  The key concept is that this world and its obstacles is fundamentally incapable of satisfying you, and true happiness comes from spiritual revelation arising from religious/mystical practises.  Jesus said something similar with: "Whoever comes to me will never be hungry again. Whoever believes in me will never be thirsty."

Or in a more secular way, consider the poem [Desiderata](https://www.sfu.ca/%7Ewainwrig/desiderata.htm).  The point of that poem isn't telling you to overcome obstacles, it's to inspire you to remain happy *regardless of* obstacles.